# Which for cycle code sqflite is more optimal when calls to an API?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I want to know if more optimal doing this :

The `idList` has 10 ids for example

```dart
final List<Animal> animalList = [];

for (int id var idList) {
  // Calls to the API 10 times
  final Animal a = await api.getAnimal(id);

  animalList.add(a);
}

// Then, we insert every item from the list but using Batch and commit

for(animal…)
  batch.insert(animal…

batch.commit…
```

I use this because I know that batch helps to optimize every insert in the database, but I want to know if it’s better doing it inside the for already like this :

```dart
for (int id var idList) {
  // Calls to the API 10 times
  final Animal a = await api.getAnimal(id);

  // Do here the insert query for every animal, but not using batch, or do I?
  insert(…
}
```

Thank you for the clarification

Comment: You are not new to this site, so please, before submitting, ensure that you have read, and understood, the information for each of the tags you attach to your question. I have removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, you may wish to [Edit] your question to use a more suitable replacement for it!

Comment: batch.insert is very fast. insert is take long time.

Comment: @A.Sang but in this case, can I use the batch inside the for where I already get the API? Thanks

Comment: sure you can use batch Everywhere. but batch is collection of queries.
single query in batch no use.

Comment: ok 1000s of single insert query take some seconds . but batch its milli seconds.

Comment: Ok, yeah because what I want is at the moment to get the API, insert the only element that I’ll use a query.insert (but it’s better batch) ? Thx!!